# Get profile IDs using regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to pull out a list of profile IDs from a string in PHP but I am having trouble with the appropriate regex expressions.

My client is adding links around names to their profile pages for example `<a href="/player/bio.asp?ID=123">John Smith</a> defeats <a href="/player/bio.asp?ID=456">James Dean</a> in a close match.`.

I would like to be able to obtain an array of IDs

```php
<?php $ids = ['123', '456']; ?>
```

Here is my code currently but it is returning no results.

```php
<?php Importer::getArticleTags('/bio.asp?ID=(?P<id>\d+)/', 'player', $newsItem['articleBody']); ?>
```

I plan to use the IDs later in a mapping exercise to a new digital space.

Comment: Escape the dot and the question mark `bio\.asp\?ID=(?P<id>\d+)` https://regex101.com/r/I5KhTl/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .  and the ? both have meaning in regex, if you want to match those characters you need to escape them with (only the first question mark)

```
<?php Importer::getArticleTags('/bio\.asp\?ID=(?P<id>\d+)/', 'player', $newsItem['articleBody']); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help both. This worked perfectly. The IDs were alphanumeric should've specified but here's the solution for:

**Numeric**

```php
<?php Importer::getArticleTags('/bio\.asp\?ID=(?P<id>\d+)/', 'player', $newsItem['articleBody']); ?>
```

**Alphanumeric**

```php
<?php Importer::getArticleTags('/bio\.asp\?ID=(?P<id>[a-zA-Z\d]+)/', 'player', $newsItem['article']); ?>
```